# Obtaining an addressable copy of a reflect.Value

Tags: go, reflection

I want to add marshalling/unmarshalling to types that I accept, in a way similar JSON custom encoding/decoding.  I have it all working great when the type implements a Marshal method (value receiver) and Unmarshal method (pointer receiver).

The Unmarshal method must obviously use a pointer receiver so that the new value is saved.  I have been told that a Marshal method using a *pointer* (not value) receiver should also be allowed.  The trouble with this is I am using a reflect.Value which is not always addressable.

Here's an edited extract of the code which panics:

```
  var v reflect.Value // passed in parameter

  t := v.Type()
  pt := reflect.TypeOf(reflect.New(t).Interface())

  if t.Implements(reflect.TypeOf((*Marshaler)(nil)).Elem()) {
    str, err = v.Interface().(Marshaler).MarshalXXX()
    // ... value receiver WORKS FINE

  } else if pt.Implements(reflect.TypeOf((*Marshaler)(nil)).Elem()) {
    str, err = v.Addr().Interface().(Marshaler).MarshalXXX()
    // ptr receiver gives PANIC value is not addressable
```

I tried creating a copy of v, but the copy is also not addressable which makes no sense to me:

```
    tmp := reflect.New(v.Type())
    tmp.Addr().Set(v)
    str, err = tmp.Interface().(Marshaler).MarshalXXX()
```

In case I have not explained this well [here is an example on the Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/oAZa1IdRjzf) for you to try:

Also while I am here: Is there a better way to get the type of a pointer to a the type than in the assignment to `pt` above?

Comment: `X(42)` is not addressable. You can't take the address of that after you already copied into the `reflect.Value`, you must start with an addressable value.

Comment: Thanks @JimB.  I am aware of this but the problem is I already have a reflect.Value that may not be addressable. I have no control of where this comes from. Ie, I need an addressable version of the reflect.Value.  There must be a way to copy a reflect.Value into a new (addressable) reflect.Value .

Comment: [CanAddr](https://pkg.go.dev/reflect#Value.CanAddr) docs defines what is "addressable": `... an element of a slice, an element of an addressable array, a field of an addressable struct, or the result of dereferencing a pointer. If CanAddr returns false, calling Addr will panic.`

Comment: Thanks @colm.anseo. I know about `CanAddr` and why a reflect.Value may not be addressable.  It's just that I need an addressable copy of a reflect.Value that comes from outside my package and I have no control of whether it is addressable or not..  I don't need to change it but apparently can't call a method with ptr receiver unless it is addressable.  Anyway I worked out the soln - see below.

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer.  The problem was I was using `Addr` instead of `Elem`.  Though that begs the question why `Set` worked, since the panic did not occur till the following line.

In summary, to create an addressable copy of a reflect.Value `v` do this:

```
  tmp := reflect.New(v.Type()) // create zero value of same type as v
  tmp.Elem().Set(v)
```

Please forgive me asking prematurely, but I had already spent 4 hours trying to solve the problem.  For completeness [here is the fix to my Go playground code in the question](https://go.dev/play/p/BGLukzULChL).

Comment: https://go.dev/play/p/H-SEgRPPmty (and I think you're mistaken about where the original panic was, you can't call `Set` on a non-addressable value)

Comment: @JimB you are right, my mistake, the panic was not where I thought.
Also thanks for the improvement to the code (avoiding some repetition) which I will use.